# Samsung Galaxy S3 does not appear on Windows computer or Mac?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, usb, samsung, usb-drivers

I'm trying to unlock a Samsung Galaxy S3 Gt-i9305 on EE running Android 4.3. I know how to unlock the phone however, when I connect the phone to my computer it does not appear at all. Usually, Android  phones have a notification saying the phone is connected as a media device or something but it doesn't appear.

I've tried this on Windows 10 technical preview and Mac Yosemite. I've tried the following:

- Installing new drivers (however I don't know if they were the correct drivers I tried    several though)
- Installing Kies and updating to the latest version on both Mac and Windows
- Putting my phone in download mode to download drivers (no drivers downloaded)
- Restarting the phone and taking out the sim

Is there anything else I can possibly do? Is it a hardware problem? I don't have USB debugging on either. Thank you for your help.

EDIT

I've tried different USB ports, they work with my S4 but not my S3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of not having my device appear on my Mac running OSX Yosemite. The only difference is that I am using a Galaxy Note 3. What made it work for me was to change the USB port. I think it may have to do with the COM port not automatically selecting or something similar.